# Excel-find column1 & column2 duplicates in the table

Tags: excel

I need to find duplicates for columns A and B.
So for example, if I have these values:

```
COLUMN A   COLUMN B     CODE  ISQUAL     ISRET      ISEXP
```

---

```
1004679    R&DCHPClass   3    QUALIFIED  Retired    Non-expired
1004679    R&DCHPClass   2    QUALIFIED  Retired    Non-expired
```

I want to be able to see all of the Matching COLUMN A & COLUMN B .

Because column A and column B will be a composite key in DB later.

Is this doable in Excel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a column and use a `COUNTIF`.

Create the column in cell G2 for example (for row 2) and put in the formula:

```
=COUNTIF(A:A, A2)
```

Fill the formula to the bottom.

The same for column B, in cell H2, use:

```
=COUNTIF(B:B, B2)
```

And fill to the bottom.

Apply a filter and all the results 2 and higher are those that appear more than once.

Comment: @EvilWashingMachine Maybe not for you, but the OP marked it as accepted, meaning it worked for them. Maybe you understood it as being duplicate *pairs* of columns A and B? Then you'd use `COUNTIFS` like so: `COUNTIFS(A:A, A2, B:B, B2)`.